# Column, parameter, or variable #6: Cannot find data type datetime2 in ASP.net core API project

Tags: asp.net, .net-core, migration, datetime2

[image]

When i run **update-database** in nuget console then datetime2 error comes, but when migration file has DateTime type for Doj field. Please provide solution.

I deleted the migration file and then regenerate it by commend **add-migration init** and then **update-database**  but not working and same error comes.
**Result** : Database created but tables not, means connection string is working.

Answer (score 0):

finally problem solved,

Actually my sql server is old version and cannot have **datetime2** type of datatype  then i have to change type of insert data DOJ
[image: changes in migration file]

then again i ran command

**update-database**

and table created successfully.